# "./gradlew assembleDebug" failing to build project created by "android create project"; error shows task not available

Tags: android

How can I get a file structure exactly like the one that is generated when a new project is created using Android Studio, while creating a project by using the command "android create project"? My aim is to build the project from the command line using the command " ./ gradlew assembleDebug" but the shell is showing that the task "assembleDebug" is not available for the projects created from the command line. But the task is available if a project has been created using Android Studio. I am suspecting this has something to do with the mismatch between the files generated when a project is created from the command line and from Android Studio. If it is possible to generate the same file structure from the command line, how to do it?

Comment: assembleDebug is task that you get from the android gradle plugin